# Dirichlet series with a single zero

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I need to find a Dirichlet series f that has the following property.

f is zero in only one point s such that Re(s) > $\sigma_c $.

Comment: $1/\zeta(s){}{}$

Comment: Why are people voting to close this?

Comment: @Lucia I have voted to close because I thought $1/\zeta(s)$ is a (relatively) obvious counterexample, but I have not realized it relies on RH. I have retracted my vote now.

Comment: Just curious: why did you *need* to find such an example?

Comment: @Wojowu: I assume that $\sigma_c$ is the abscissa of absolute convergence. If this is the case, then $1/\zeta(s)$ is not an example. In fact, not Dirichlet series with an Euler product can be an example.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta $\sigma_c$ is a standard notation for the abscissa of convergence, while abscissa of absolute convergence is usually denoted with $\sigma_a$.

Answer (score 23):

That such a Dirichlet series exists was a conjecture of Balazard, which was 
recently resolved by [Hilberdink and Saias](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.11880.pdf). If the Riemann Hypothesis is 
true, then $1/\zeta(s)$ would provide such an example (with the abscissa of conditional convergence being $1/2$), and the goal was to find an unconditional example.